# How do I pass a variable to a shell expression run with `sh -c`?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, find

I have the following script that is run in a folder that looks like `log_file/2020/04/30`
This folder contains a `server.log` file. And there is one for each date.

My script

```
path_date=$(echo "$(pwd)" | grep -oP '\d+/\d+(/\d+)?')
date=${path_date//\//-}
echo date: $date


find ./ -name "server.log*" |  xargs -i sh -c 'filename=$(basename {}) && new_filename=${date}-$filename && echo $(readlink -f {}) ${new_filename}' >> ~/logs/server-logs.list
```

I expect the output file `~/logs/server-logs.list` to contain lines like this

```
log_file/2020/04/30/server.log 2020-04-30-server.log
```

but instead it is outputting

```
log_file/2020/04/30/server.log -server.log
```

The variable `$date` does not exist in the context of `sh -c`

How do I pass a variable from the current shell to a shell expression run with `sh -c`?

Comment: @steeldriver : updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [this brilliant answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/236063) from [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) on Unix & Linux SE.
I don't want to duplicate it, just the essential parts:

> Never embed `{}` in the shell code! That creates a command injection vulnerability.

Rather use

```
xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo "$1";' xargs-sh {}
```

or

```
find -exec sh -c 'echo "$1";' find-sh {} \;
```

The name `xargs-sh` / `find-sh` is just a name and can be anything (you will see `_` a lot for it), but it will make errors more easy to track, as this will be part of the error message.

---

Btw: When using `find`, you should better use `-exec` instead of piping to `xargs`. If you still do it for any reason, use NUL-delimited output to avoid your script to choke if your file names include newlines which is not very common but valid:

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```

---

Regarding on how to add `$date` to your sh -c script:

Variables in single quotes won't get expanded. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192420/how-do-i-use-variables-in-single-quoted-strings) or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209971/is-there-any-way-to-print-value-inside-variable-inside-single-quote).

But in this case, it is imo safer to add the date as argument to your `sh -c` script:

```
find -exec sh -c 'date="$1"; file="$2"; ...' find-sh "$date" {} \;
```

Comment: "use NUL-delimited output to avoid your script to choke if your file names include newlines which is not very common but valid" : overengineering at its finest

Comment: @belun hackers love your opinion, makes them celebrate.

Comment: how does any of this help with my question? i asked about $date needed to be seen by the stuff inside 'sh -c'

Comment: @belun syntax is: sh -c 'script' $0 $1 $2 .. example `sh -c 'echo "Usage: $0: arguments: $@"' script 1 2 3`

Comment: i really do not care about this improvement as it does decrease readability (by introducing the confusing 'xargs-sh {}', which btw i have no clue what it is for) for the purpose of reducing some vulnerability that i do not have a problem with (that filesystem is under strict access control and the running script is a personal script). the issue mentioned in the question is with the variable $date from the current shell that runs find ... i have spent 1h now reading on crap that is not really helpful

Comment: I updated the answer how to add $date. Regarding the security thing. It might seem, in your exact case when you have control over all the input, security implications are not relevant, but it makes a lot of sense in all other cases and it is a good habit to always do it and learn it the right way from the beginning.

Comment: @bac0n ok, now it all make sense: 'find-sh' is in fact $0 from sh -c 'script' $0 $1 $2. and it is not used (that is why it was even mentioned that the name could be anything and most times people use _)

Comment: why is 'find-sh' needed as parameter? isn't this enough? find -exec sh -c 'date="$0"; file="$1"; ...'  "$date" {} \;

Comment: ye, ye, ye, conventions, learned behaviour, #itslikethatinotherplaces. in this case, this is how 'sh -c' works (from man sh: -c string
If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.), so use it fearlessly; ps: i should have just looked in the manual so 'sh' in the first place (oh, well...)

Comment: dont use $0 as an argument its reseved for "script name" ... its common to use just a _ as name.... `sh -c 'echo $1' _ $date` $0 will be shaved of in special parameters like `$@` and `$*`, for example in error messages `sh -c 'ehcu $1' MyScript 1` ... MyScript: 1: ehcu: not found